# Not able to read values from the named range using Office.js API

Tags: excel, office-js

I am new to Excel Add-ins and Office.js. I am trying to explore to code add-in projects.

Here i'm trying to read values from a Named Range. Firstly I'm trying to get `range` object and then load values for that `range`.

I'm not able to get those values but this code neither throws an error nor prints values to the console:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var range = ctx.workbook.names.getItem("MyRange").getRange();
    range.load("values");
    return ctx.sync(function () {
        console.log("required range values -> ");
        console.log(range.values);
    });
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log("error info is" + e.message);
});
```

Here I already have `MyRange` in my sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code that you've posted, you're missing the `.then(...)` after `return ctx.sync()`.

The following (JavaScript) code snippet gets the named range **ExpensesHeader** and then writes the values of that range to the console.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    var myNamedItem = sheet.names.getItem("ExpensesHeader");
    var myNamedRange = myNamedItem.getRange();

    myNamedRange.load("values");

    return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("values: " + JSON.stringify(myNamedRange.values));
        });
});
```

And here's the same snippet, but in TypeScript:

```
Excel.run(async (ctx) => {
    const sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sample");
    const myNamedItem = sheet.names.getItem("ExpensesHeader");
    const myNamedRange = myNamedItem.getRange();

    myNamedRange.load("values");

    await ctx.sync();

    console.log("values: " + JSON.stringify(myNamedRange.values));
});
```

You can quickly and easily try these code snippets yourself in Excel by using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/da3f56d9510329d5ea04bf00ced5c870.

Comment: Happy to help!  Can you please mark my answer as "Accepted", so that others are more likely to benefit from this information in the future?  Thanks!